# Ubuntu 10.04 minimal installer hangs

Tags: installation, 10.04, ubuntu-minimal

I need to install an old version of Ubuntu (namely, 10.04) in a virtual machine using VirtualBox. Unfortunately it fails. My host operating system is Ubuntu Precise 32bit. I downloaded the 32bit image.

Just after selecting the mirror, the next screen asks for a http proxy (which I leave blank), then the "Downloading release files" window flashes briefly, finally it disappears and the screen stays blue with a grey band on the bottom.

I have tried to install the current Ubuntu version on the same virtual machine and it works perfectly. I tried VmWare Player, and it hangs the same way!!

I tried to google for it, but it seems nobody has experienced this?

Thanks!

Comment: exactly the same for me with 12.04 minimal installer (and also on 10.04, which I tried first). I'm on VirtualBox 3.1.2, which version are you using?

Comment: The problem with 10.04-mini guest persists, even after upgrading the host to 12.10. My VirtualBox version is 4.2.4 from Oracle's PPA. No solution so far. So frustrating :(

Comment: [Not an answer]
After adding the bounty I lost comment everywhere, so I'm posting here sorry...I have the same problem for Ubuntu 11.10 and Lubuntu 12.04 installs using either UK mirror.

Comment: @Ads20000 - I've returned your bounty.  Please raise your own question.  This was specifically for 10.04 minimal.  I'll close this now since its now off-topic.  Make sure you are referring to a supported version of ubuntu and put as much details such as memory/graphics card of the host

Comment: This also happened to me, but on latest 14.04 it works fine :)